# Problem with backslash and quote escape sequence in Python?

Tags: python, sql, escaping, character

I'm doing a project for SQL injection detecting; I have this query:

```
"v: select * from users where id=1 + @'\' union select 1,version() -- 1"
```

and I need to detect the escape sequence `"'\'";` I've searched and I find something about module `re` but I didn't understand what I have to write..

How could I resolve?

---

the problem is that if I do:

`myStr="v: select * from users where id=1 + @'\' union select 1,version() -- 1" print myStr.find("'\")`

I get -1, but I want detect the presence of '\, because this is an escape sequence used for the inkections

Comment: Your query is choc full of problems.  For starters, you are doing a union query with `select *`.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking....what you want to do?  You need to be more clear.  Note that if those are Python string literals, the backslash is superfluous.  An escaped quote is just a quote.